# Exclude embedded.mongodb.enabled for certain test

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, junit5, testcontainers

I'm working here on some tests, I start from the bottom, reactiveRepository and successfully wrote all necessary tests with `com.playtika.testcontainers.embedded-mongodb` and `embedded.mongodb.enabled: true` in test/resources bootstrap.yml

Now I moved one layer up, to the @Services, but I spot that `testcontainers` still executes `embedded-mongodb` which I don't need, as I'm just mocking repository for Services tests:

```
@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
blah blah blah() {
  Mockito.when(userRepository.findByUsername(loginRequest.getUsername())).thenReturn(Mono.just(fakeUser));
}
```

Any hints on how to exclude `embedded-mongo` autoconfiguration?
or set `embedded.mongodb.enabled: false` for specific test case?

Answer (score 0):

you can create two separate test profiles and a bootstrap.yaml for each for that profile where one having embedded-mongodb with `embedded.mongodb.enabled: true` ( e.g. for integration test cases) & other one with `embedded.mongodb.enabled: false` (e.g. for unit test cases).

For more, you can refer this blog: https://dev.to/sivalabs/springboot-integration-testing-using-testcontainers-starter-13h2